# How to filter IP6 and already known IP4 addresses from NSLOOKUP answer out?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, find, compare, findstr

I have the problem that some DNS entries provide aliases and addionanal IP6 addresses, while others do provide several IP4 addresses and those may change from answer to answer.

Asking DNS servers for IP4 only, does result in timeout for the script and does not solve the changing (loadbalanced) IP4 addresses.

For test you may use these domains for example:

- www.stackoverflow.com
- www.heise.de
- www.dell.de

These are nice examples because, first domain does provides an alias after the IP address which I could filter by find easily. But second does provide an IP6 additionally which should get filtered too and last not least Dell provides different addresses with almost each returned answer.

This is the partial piece of my code:

```
set TESTDNS=www.dell.de
set TESTIP=143.166.83.190

FOR /F "skip=1 delims=: tokens=2 usebackq" %%j in (`nslookup %TESTDNS% 2^>NUL 1^| find "Address"`) do set XIP=%%j 
set XIP=%XIP: =%

do more like compare etc. ....
if NOT %TESTIP%==%XIP% ( ... )
```

Could someone show me how to filter IP6 adresses out (maybe with findstr [0-9] - but the more how to check if my last known IP address is in the provided new answer, because if so i do not need to change it in my configs.

**SOLUTION:**

From MC ND's answer i used his function as straight code (for use in another Loop), without use of call. The only thing i really changed exept of var names is to add strip whitespaces from the IP which does otherwise break the function as `"1.2.3.4" =! "1.2.3.4 "` D)

```
for x do ( ...

      REM go get dns resolution and set vars to test and compare
      set "XIP="
        for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('nslookup "%TESTDNS%" 2^>nul ^| findstr /i /r /c:"address[e]*[s]*:.*\." /c:"address[ ]*=.*\." /c:"^[   ][  ]*[0-9].*\." ') do (
            rem get nslookup output
            set "_line=%%a"
            rem remove spaces
            set "_line=!_line: =!"
            rem parse line
            for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:=" %%b in ("!_line!") do (
                rem retrieve the correct section of the line
                if "%%c"=="" (
                    set "XTIPX=%%b"
                ) else (
                    set "XTIPX=%%c"
                )
                REM trim whitespaces from var
                set XTIPX=!XTIPX: =!
                rem test address match to old address
                if "!XTIPX!"=="%TESTIP%" (
                    set "XIP=!XTIPX!"
                    goto endRESTESTDNS
                )
                rem if no match, the first address found is saved
                if not defined XIP set "XIP=!XTIPX!"
            )
        )
        :endRESTESTDNS

do more like compare etc. ....
```

experimental code:

```
                      @ECHO OFF
          SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

          REM ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ BLAT EMAIL CONFIG ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          set eMailTO=someone@somedomain.somewhere
          set eMailFROM=dnstestscript
          set server=0.0.0.0
          REM you have to install blat of course, here "echo blat ..." is used where it would be
          REM useful to send an email on interesting items, but it is also sent to shell and log
          REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

          REM ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ SCRIPT CONFIG ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          set "XScriptnamE=%~n0"
          set "XSCRIPTDIR=%~dp0"
          set "LOGDIR=%XSCRIPTDIR%\%XScriptnamE%"
          if not exist "%LOGDIR%" mkdir "%LOGDIR%"
          set "LOG=%LOGDIR%\%XScriptnamE%.log"
          REM make errorlooging expand
          set "XLOGX=xpipex && type xpipex && type xpipex >> %LOG%"
          REM or make individual run logs
          REM set "LOG=%LOGDIR%\%XScriptnamE%-%STAMP%.log"
          REM not global vars come here
          set "DNSTESTFILE=%XSCRIPTDIR%\dnstests.txt"
          REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          REM do never set something here at errorlog plz otherwise compare of happened errors wont work
          set errorlog=
          pushd=%XSCRIPTDIR%
          REM ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ MAKE DATE ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
          REM make timestamp (date reverse)
          set STAMP=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%--%ldt:~8,2%-%ldt:~10,2%--%ldt:~12,2%-%ldt:~15,3%
          REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          echo ================================================== >> %LOG%
          echo   Script run at %STAMP% >> %LOG%
          REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

          REM ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ START ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          REM if the script is run in cmd we see enoght information to follow actions but they are written to a log file too for sheduled use

          REM ++++++++++++ make a loop for each line in file ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


          REM read them in different vars to call processing
          REM check for test file
          if NOT exist "%DNSTESTFILE%" (
            set errorlog=%errorlog% : error dns file not exist :
            echo blat error dnsfile
            echo error dnsfile not exist >> %log%
            )
          REM read test file
          set Counter=1
          for /f %%s in (%DNSTESTFILE%) do (
            set "Line_!Counter!=%%s"
            set /a Counter+=1
            )
          set /a NumLines=Counter - 1
          REM make a backup of old test file before nulling it, by files date you see last ip change
          copy /y %DNSTESTFILE% %DNSTESTFILE%.bak 2>&1 > %XLOGX% 
          REM as i found no way to rewrite the specific line i choose to read out all lines in vars, now we nul the file and rewrite lines later
          type NUL > %DNSTESTFILE%
          REM now use vars to call processing
          for /l %%r in (1,1,%NumLines%) do (
            set "q=!Line_%%r!"
            echo. >> %log%
            echo.
            call :check !q!
            )
          REM did all go well or what did we miss?
          if NOT "%errorlog%."=="." (
          echo.
          echo blat summary %errorlog%!
          echo. >> %LOG%
          echo %errorlog%! >> %LOG%
          )
          REM ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ END +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          REM next line tells us script did run through code while one may want to save this lines
          echo ==================script finished================= >> %log%
          del xpipex
          break
          goto :eof
          REM ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

          REM +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ PROCESSING +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
          :check
              REM trim whitespace from beginning and end of line
              for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%z in ("!q!") do ( 
              set "line=!q!"
                REM test if line is valid dns AND ip address syntax BUT only informational because of limited regular expression support of findstr and "1234.2.3.4" is also accepted as well formatted address
                echo !line! | findstr /i /r "^[a-z0-9-]*\.[a-z0-9-]*\.[a-z0-9-]*=[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" >NUL || (
                echo blat error in dns test line syntax with: !line!
                set errorlog=%errorlog% : error in dns test line syntax with: !line! :
                )
              REM test that trimmed line matches at least once "^char=number$" and set vars for test
              echo !line! | findstr /i "^[a-z]*=[0-9]*$" >NUL && do (
              for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%x in ("!q!") do set TESTDNS=%%~x&set TESTIP=%%~y 
              )
              REM trim whitespace from beginning and end of var
              set TESTDNS=%TESTDNS: =%
              set TESTIP=%TESTIP: =%
              echo testing %TESTDNS% to %TESTIP%
              echo checking %TESTDNS%: >> %LOG%
              REM go get dns resolution and set vars to test and compare
    echo. ############################
    nslookup %TESTDNS%
    echo. ############################
              set "XIP="
                for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('nslookup "%TESTDNS%" 2^>nul ^| findstr /i /r /c:"address[e]*[s]*:.*\." /c:"address[ ]*=.*\." /c:"^[   ][  ]*[0-9].*\." ') do (
                    rem get nslookup output
    echo testing %TESTDNS% to %TESTIP% -1
                    set "_line=%%a"
                    rem remove spaces
                    set "_line=!_line: =!"
                    rem parse line
                    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:=" %%b in ("!_line!") do (
                        rem retrieve the correct section of the line
    echo testing %TESTDNS% to %TESTIP% -2
                        if "%%c"=="" (
                            set "XTIPX=%%b"
                        ) else (
                            set "XTIPX=%%c"
                        )

    echo testing %TESTDNS% to %TESTIP% -3 "!XTIPX!"
    echo !XTIPX! > 1.txt
    echo %TESTIP% > 2.txt

              REM trim whitespace from beginning and end of var
              rem  set XTIPX=!XTIPX: =!

                        rem test address match to old address
                        if "!XTIPX!"=="%TESTIP%" (
    echo testing %TESTDNS% to %TESTIP% -4 !XTIPX!
                            set "XIP=!XTIPX!"
                            goto endRESTESTDNS
                        )
                        rem if no match, the first address found is saved
                        if not defined XIP set "XIP=!XTIPX!"
    echo testing %TESTDNS% to %TESTIP% -5
                    )
                )
                :endRESTESTDNS
                REM if dsn did change
                if NOT %XIP%==%TESTIP% (
                  echo %TESTDNS% now is %XIP%
                  REM inform us
                  echo blat dns for given %TESTDNS% did change from %TESTIP% TO %XIP%!
                  echo dns did change from %TESTIP% TO %XIP%! >> %LOG%
                  REM fill a log-var to report allover later in mail for example
                  set errorlog=%errorlog% : dns for given %TESTDNS% dis change from %TESTIP% TO %XIP%! :
                  REM do not forget to write back
                  echo %TESTDNS%=%XIP% >> %DNSTESTFILE%
                  )
                if %XIP%==%TESTIP% (
                  REM if dns did not change
                  echo ip did not change 
                  REM we should not forget to write back the route to our testfile
                  echo %TESTDNS%=%XIP% >> %DNSTESTFILE%
                  echo - OK >> %LOG%
                  )
    )

          :EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

    call :TESTIP "www.dell.de" "1.1.1.1" IP

    echo %IP%

    exit /B


:TESTIP name oldip retrievedIpVar

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "_name=%~1"
    set "_oldIP=%~2"
    set "_return="
    rem Need a variable with a tab in it to use in findstr
    call :getTab tab

    rem Loop over nslookup filtering output
    rem Get lines in the form 
    rem     Address / Addresses : followed by IP
    rem     blank line start and ip
    rem     www.somewhere.com internet address = ip     

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%a in ('nslookup "%_name%" 2^>nul ^| findstr /i /r /c:"address[e]*[s]*:.*\." /c:"address[ ]*=.*\." /c:"^[ %tab%][ %tab%]*[0-9].*\." ') do (
        rem get nslookup output
        set "_line=%%a"
        rem remove spaces
        set "_line=!_line: =!"
        rem remove tabs
        set "_line=!_line:%tab%=!"

        rem parse line
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:=" %%b in ("!_line!") do (
            rem retrieve the correct section of the line
            if "%%c"=="" (
                set "XIP=%%b"
            ) else (
                set "XIP=%%c"
            )
            rem test address match to old address
            if "!XIP!"=="%_oldIP%" (
                set "_return=!XIP!"
                goto endTESTIP
            )
            rem if no match, the first address found is saved
            if not defined _return set "_return=!XIP!"
        )
    )

:endTESTIP
    endlocal & set "%~3=%_return%"
    goto :EOF

:getTab var
    for /f tokens^=^*^ delims^= %%x in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do ( set "%~1=%%x" )
    goto :EOF
```

Skip the first line (dns server info). Use colon and equal as delimiter. Take second token and all after it, as address can include a port in the form 99.99.99.99:999. If port is not necessary, change token to `token=2` and `set  "XIP=%%a"`

The simplest way to exclude a IPv6 is to filter and get only Address strings with a dot in it.

EDITED - Changed to adapt to balanced addresses, which include a `=` in the output before the address.

EDITED 2 - The number of cases is greater than i think. Changed the code to handle more cases and get more IPs

EDITED 3 - Adapted to integrate into OP solution

EDITED 4 - Handle initial tabs in line in nslookup output

EDITED 5 - Correct problem with tab parsing

Comment: token one puts out www.dell.de instaed of the IP and token 2 just a "=" - if i include it in my script it breaks the Loop with www.chip.de. while www.heise.de would return an IP6 i remember now not dell. here is my big script, you may use the smaller one just Monitoring dns without Setting routes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20188523/2167103

Comment: @peet: my fault. Findstr filter is wrong. Updated. Anyway, in my nslookup output there is no `=`. Don't know from where it comes from in your output.

Comment: now i only get "=" as Output, i did use exactly your code in bat file?

Comment: Can you post the output or your nslookup? As said, i have get no `=` in my output?

Comment: did so in question to Keep formatting.  i could imagine your code not finding "Addresses" but at the Moment all i get is "="

Comment: @peet: I'm behind a corporate proxy and can't see much of the outputs of dns commands. Updated to your output and to what google images show as possible nslookup output.

Comment: @"MC ND" - i updated output to your last code, now the IP4 do work, but when IP6 is provided too it does not find the IP4?

Comment: guess it is because the second and more addresses are listed without the tag "address", only blanks before. this is going into my other Problem to filter if my testip is just ONE of the many provided answered ip's.

Comment: i would need to testcompare whole answer to my testip and if not found on any line take the first IP4 address for XIP.

Comment: but script going mad with loadbalanced ip's and is busting Routing table, will try your new code now

Comment: still faster as my origin code, how can i Input a var "OLDIP" and check if one of the tested lines does include it already, because if so no change is needed in my routing table. in this case the returned XIP should be the same as OLDIP.

Comment: too the new code does not find IP4 anymore if IP6 is provieded?

Comment: wow, thnx for your efforts, i'm sad to Report the above in question posted Outputs. if IP4 only the script returnes the first found always. if IP6 is provided, still no IP4 gets found anymore?

Comment: @peet: no, the problem is probably (i have no way to test now) tabs in output lines of nslookup. In your sample output, ipv6 is in the same line that Address label, and ipv4 in next line. I can't test, but tabs are a good candidate for the problem. Changed code to test for tabs in lines.

Comment: you ar eright there is a tab and two blanks before the IP4 and a return after the IP6 of course, but still i get no IP6 and still i get the first IP4 no matter of OLDIP. maybe you could take a look at it at home?

Comment: you are great man, that did the trick, now the IP6 and too the OLDIP's get found - great code, thank you

Comment: did i understand your code right, that the call tab is to produce a tabbed var and has no need in real code have to integrate now into my big dns scripts D)

Comment: and goto endTESTIP is only good style while it is not neccessary because code behind would only set var if not already set, right?

Comment: @peet: Added tab remove from lines. This was the reason for not returning old ip. goto endTESTIP is to not continue looping once old ip is found. And the tab var is to allow tab search/replace. If i add a tab character in code, when copy/pasted, not sure tab character is keep. So, i just generated it.

Comment: i do not get your code integrated in my big script, either (as straight code) the returned IP gets not updated with each run (although resetting XIP to NUL) or other way with using call the script breaks with Syntax error and a "("?

Comment: your actual (last) code does not work without the tab call, without it it does return always the first IP4 and if IP6 is provided it return nothing ""?!

Comment: thats too why i did not get in code as straight code without using calls.

Comment: ok now i understood the tab workaround D) and made it straight as in my edited question, only old ip does not get recognized?

Comment: the whitespaces broke the compare (was not error of the loop), don't know why they did not break in nested call, maybe was an effect of your TAB routine. if you update your code with the trim too, would be nice and save function for all users. thnx in advance.

Comment: @peet: maybe i'm not understanding it, but, if 10 lines after you have removed all the spaces, from where are you getting the spaces you trim? But you have fogotten to remove the tabs.

Comment: guess because all vars are in "quotes" and get expanded. gues !x! != "!x!". i did echo the vars at all places and did pipe them to a file at the stage of comparison, there i had to notice that one got 1 blank and the other 2 blanks after the ip. this way the comparison works now. i did not remove the quotes to let other adopt code for char strings more easy (and because it is better code), thus only my extra whitespace killer has to be removed in that case.

Comment: @peet: Sure `!x! != "!x!"` but, what i say is, if you have run `set "_line=!_line: =!"` and removed all spaces from `_line` var, when you do `for ... in ("!_line!")` from where did the space come? I don't see it.

Comment: me neither, i pasted my testcode above. i can't reproduce the blanks at the moment. weird. i remember that night i recognized the script never running "case -4", it always -3 and next hop -5. ido remember too that i did Close and reopen cmd box from time to time as i had to recognize the script, after excessive testing, not always reflected changes in code correct. maybe that was the Problem, although i would swear i did reopen box with that Problem several times. is it possible that some combined other dns answer could get your tab trim code confused? like "tab blank blank tab tab ip-adress"?

Comment: @peet: In your test code, no tab remove is included (tab deletion line not present) and no tabs in findstr (maybe copypaste). And outside of the nslookup code, just after "** PROCESSING **" line, `for %%x in (!q!) ... set line=!q!`? What is %%x used for? And, INSIDE this loop, there is again for %%x.

Comment: Tabs got and get replaced by blanks in stackoverflow. in origin there i have real Tabs inside instead of your tab-generator called vars. it works fine taht way. in the first for Loop %%x is the whole line, in the second the first found pattern match and %%y the second. all behaving correct as for breaks the var it was not neccessary to Change var, while it would be better style (did change it :).

Comment: too changed doubled %%r D) but still don't see what went wrong and now does not.